# On mobile, my first responsive card won't appear until the screen is touched

Tags: jquery, css, responsive

On this page: http://limitlesshoops.com/pr0digies/home.html --- see the [source code](https://view-source:http://limitlesshoops.com/pr0digies/home.html) --- the first card won't show until I scroll or tap the screen, while the original codepen (https://codepen.io/Katiae/pen/zwjmbW) works perfectly. **Any suggestions?** The only thing I've added to the page is a navbar. Thank you, in advance.

```
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');

// Colors
@dark-blue: #32325d;
@gray: #f8f8f8;

// Mobile first
*,
*::before,
*::after { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: @gray;
}

body {
  padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
  font-family: 'Raleway',Sans-serif;
  color: @dark-blue;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  margin: 0;
  @media(min-width: 40rem) {
    padding: 2rem;
  }
}

//Flex container
.container {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: box;
  -moz-display: box;
  -ms-display: flexbox;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

// Cards
.cards {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  @media(min-width: 40rem) {
    width: 50%;
  }
  @media(min-width: 56rem) {
    width: 33.3%;
  }

  .card-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s;

    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      .card-image {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }

  // Content
  .card-info {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5em;
  }

  .card-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    color: #32325d;
    margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  }

  // Images
  .card-image{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
    opacity: 0.91;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mak sure you run your stuff with in $(document).ready(function () { // your stuff })

Comment: I've seen that before, but I don't know how to apply what you're saying. My guess is that would apply to the javascript portion, but mine is at the base of the page. The times I've seen $(document) stuff is usually prior to the HTML. Any further help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is not loaded completely when the script starts,
do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var images;

  images = ["https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/s1.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/s2.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/s3.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/s4.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/s5.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/s6.jpg",
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/p1.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/p2.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/p3.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/p4.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/p5.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/p6.jpg",
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/f1.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/f2.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/f4.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/f5.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/f6.jpg",
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/d1.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/d2.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/d3.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/d4.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/d5.jpg", 
  "https://fiftyallstars.com/Images/fitness/d6.jpg"];

  $('div.card-image').each(function() {
    var random_image_index;
    random_image_index = Math.floor(images.length * Math.random());
    return $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + 
     images[random_image_index] + ')');
  });

})
```

Comment: I assume you mean to add that script into the head section. I've done so, but still nothing happens. I tried to remove the repetitive code from the base, but that just broke everything. What you're saying seems simple enough, but maybe I'm just doing it completely wrong